# Как посчитать числа в input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В input, кроме последнего вводятся числа и автоматически пишется ответ в последний input.
Первые 4 input могут быть пустыми.
Как такое можно сделать?

```css
input {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="price_0" value="" placeholder="price_0">
    +
    <input type="text" id="price_1" value="" placeholder="price_1">
    -
    <input type="text" id="price_2" value="" placeholder="price_2">
    -
    <input type="text" id="price_3" value="" placeholder="price_3">
    =
    <input type="text" id="price_4" value="" placeholder="price_4">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как такое можно сделать?

Например так...

```js
const oa = document.querySelectorAll('#box input')
oa.forEach(o => o.addEventListener('input', _ => {
  const val = [...oa].reduce((s, o, i) => {
    const v = +o.value
    if (i < 2) s += v
    else s -= v
    return s
  }, 0)
  document.querySelector('#price_4').value = val
}))
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<span id='box'>
  <input type="text" id="price_0" value="" placeholder="price_0"> +
  <input type="text" id="price_1" value="" placeholder="price_1"> -
  <input type="text" id="price_2" value="" placeholder="price_2"> -
  <input type="text" id="price_3" value="" placeholder="price_3"> =
</span>
<input type="text" id="price_4" value="" placeholder="price_4">
```

По просьбе ТСа привожу еще один пример, который зависит от `+` и `-`, стоящих перед инпутами

```js
const oa = document.querySelectorAll('#box input')
oa.forEach(o => o.addEventListener('input', _ => {
  const val = [...oa].reduce((s, o) => {
    const v = +o.value
    const act = o.previousSibling.wholeText
    if (/\-/.test(act)) s -= v
    else s += v
    return s
  }, 0)
  document.querySelector('#price_4').value = val
}))
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<span id='box'>
  - <input type="text" id="price_0" value="" placeholder="price_0"> +
  <input type="text" id="price_1" value="" placeholder="price_1"> +
  <input type="text" id="price_2" value="" placeholder="price_2"> -
  <input type="text" id="price_3" value="" placeholder="price_3"> =
</span>
<input type="text" id="price_4" value="" placeholder="price_4">
```

Comment: Что-то я код такой вообще не понимаю.  Если `price_1 + price_2 - price_0 - price_3`, как код изменить?

Comment: @steep, в комментарии такое не показать... Как вариант задай еще один вопрос, де "у меня есть вот так", как теперь сделать "вот эдак". Тогда можно будет воспользоваться ответом и показать другой вариант скрипта.

Comment: @steep, как вариант - поменять `input`ы местами 1, 2 потом 0 и 3...

Comment: Местами менять не удобно пользоваться потом будет. А дополнить ответ нельзя? Зачем эти вопросы плодить

Comment: @steep, если не менять местами - как тогда `price_0` делать отрицательным? По твоей записи первый `input` всегда положительный

Comment: @steep, смотри второй скрипт в ответе. Такое устроит?